# Как переопределить AssemblyVersion одно проекта для других проектов в csproj файле

Tags: c#, build, assembly, msbuild

У меня есть проект и в нем в `AssemblyVersion` стоит версия, из за того что она расходится с версией из другого пакета у меня не совсем корректно отрабатывает `justmock` если говорить детальней не может мокать интерфейсы с сигнатурой классов классов из той библиотеки.

Но я не могу просто взять и написать тут нужные цифры:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.0.0")]
```

Поэтому мне нужно переопределить эту версию в `csproj` тех проектов которые используют этот проект.

Подключение этого проекта выглядит примерно так:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\test.csproj">
  <Project>{33c44117-a2ba-1111-c3e5-253e77882995}</Project>
  <Name>Test</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Возможно можно как то переопределить это в `.sln`.
Буду благодарен за любые советы.